# Long running operation did not complete, continued in background

Tags: apex, debugging

I am debugging a apex trigger/class and is using the Developer Console. When I click on my log entry it seems like it loads the logs and then I get this popup:

[image]

The thing is the operation never returns with anything. I closed the developer console then logged out and tried it again and the same result.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I am receiving the same error lately. How did you resolve this issue?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was only ever an intermittent issue and several years down the line, seems unlikely to be resolved.

Answer (score 2):

You need to manually download the logs. Go to 'File' then 'Download Log'.

[image]

Good Luck!